# Как перенести только один .csv файл из одной папки в другую, переименовав его?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Есть задача найти в текущем каталоге файл с расширением .csv и перенести его в другой каталог. Надо учесть, что в исходном каталоге может быть сразу несколько таких файлов. В таком случае надо переносить только первый из них. В каталог назначения его надо сохранять под другим названием.
Я попробовал написать нужный скрипт сам, но не знаю как в такой реализации получить имя файла для его перемещения:

```
if $name = ls *.csv; then
echo $name; else echo "ERROR"; fi;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/local/plot_lin/src/
find * -name "*.csv" -type f |
if read file
then
  echo "$file"
  mv $file "new_file_name.csv"
else
  echo "No files"
fi
```

Попробуй вот этот код
/usr/local/plot_lin/src/ - папка поиска

Comment: надеюсь, вы в курсе, что `find` по умолчанию не производит **никакой** сортировки вывода, и «первый файл» с точки зрения человека может быть далеко не первым в выдаче предложенного вами скрипта.

Comment: Не спорю, но не было сказано как сортировать и нужно ли.

Comment: явно сказано не было. но приведён пример: `ls *.csv`. который, понятно, возвращает **отсортированный** список файлов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin TIL `ls` сортирует её вывод по алфавиту (чтобы это не значило) по умолчанию (как и задокументировано). Как известно очевидных интерфейсов не бывает — всему приходится учиться ("There is no intuitive interface, not even the nipple. It's all learned."). К примеру, порядок `os.listdir()` вывода в Питоне (и соответствующих системных интерфейсов, на которых она реализована) не гарантирован.

Answer (score 3):

люблю однострочники.

```
$ ls *.csv | head -n 1 | xargs -I{} mv {} /новое.место/новое.имя
```

Comment: Слишком сложно: `mv -v \`ls *.csv | head -n 1\` /another/folder`

Comment: @igumnov, тоже можно, хоть и теряется наглядность. и, естественно, без backtick-ов `\``: конструкция `$(...)` — входит в *posix*.

Comment: Или так (в переменной $name */новое.место/новое.имя*) mv ``ls *.csv 2>/dev/null | head -1`` $name >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo  .csv files not found  / блин, что за форматер? не могу вставить обратные кавычки перед `ls` и после `-1`

Comment: Еще можно на самом деле два символа выиграть если
вместо `head -n 1` просто `head -1` писать.

Comment: @avp, используйте конструкцию `$(...)` вместо backtick-ов `\``. помимо большего удобства при вложенности конструкций, она вполне «переносима», так как входит в [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)

Comment: Особенно в SO комментариях :)

Comment: @avp, в so-комментариях в таких случаях надо пользоваться backslash-ами: \\`

Comment: Ну, да. `$(...)` замечательно вкладывается в backslash-ы

Answer (score 1):

Если много файлов (например, `ls` или `mv` не может скушать список аргументов), то искать надо таким [однострочником](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899746/use-xargs-to-mv-the-find-directory-into-another-directory/17764448#17764448):

```
find /source/dir/ -name "*.csv" -print0 | head -1 | xargs -0 -I % mv % /target/dir/
```

*xargs* используем: для **Linux** (и Cygwin) с ключом `-I`, для **FreeBSD/OS X** с ключом `-J`, вместо знака `%` можно использовать любой символ/букву: `find ... | xargs -I i mv i`

Более того, используя `find <...> -print0 | xargs -0 <command>`, мы страхуемся на кривые имена файлов (если в имени файлов есть пробелы).

Answer (score 0):

```
ls /sourse_dir/ | grep -m1 .csv | xargs -I{} mv {} /target_dir/$RANDOM.csv
```

В таком варианте вне зависимости от наличия пробелов в имени файла он копируется в нужную директорию и переименовывается случайным образом ($RANDOM), не заменяя предыдущие уже скопированные файлы.